# Can an operating system be considered as Graphical User Interfaces?

Tags: user-interface, operating-system

So I've been searching the Internet and I can't seem to find any answer that explicitly explain why operating systems can be considered as Graphical User Interfaces. So I' am hoping someone would explain why it can be a GUI or the other way around.

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface - self-explanatory, see the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my view an operating system is the complete interface between all interested parties (hardware, services, user) whereas a GUI just gives the users (some predefined) access to the system resources. Users might even run more than one GUI on a single system. Each user might choose her or his own flavour of GUI which fits them best to interact with the system. They may even choose to use no GUI at all and be content with a command line interface (CLI).

For me GUIs are a component of an os and not the other way around.

I hope this helps to sort out the different concepts.